# Fallback to Basic authentication if Windows authentication fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis

I have the following requirements for my ASP.NET MVC application

1. The first GET request sent to a specific page should be authenticated by Windows Authentication.
2. Based on some database checks, user could be recognized as unauthorized and the application should respond with 401.
3. In this case the user should have a possibility to enter credentials of other account. Then second request should be sent to Web application with Basic authentication for entered credentials. Basic authentication is a must-have requirement here, because in this flow we perform impersonated access to the documents in network share (see [The Double-Hop Problem](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/knowledgecast/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem/) for more details)

**My problem:**

I can't make the browser to fallback to Basic authentication and show the dialog for entering credentials. The browser receives response with `WWW-Authenticate` challenges for both Windows and Basic authentication, and just resends GET request with Windows authentication again.

I do understand why this happens. According to [Authentication Precedence and Behavior in IIS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/parvez/2013/09/21/authentication-precedence-in-iis/):

> The client picks up the most secure authentication mechanism(windows)
>   from the list provided by the server and takes necessary steps to
>   provide the required information to the server.

However I can't limit the response to challenge only Basic authentication within my ASP.NET Application. Seems like `WWW-Authenticate` headers are added by IIS (somewhere inside [Windows Authentication Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/introduction-to-iis/introduction-to-iis-architecture#security-modules)) after ASP.NET pipeline. I'm returning `Unauthorized(new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic"))` from controller action however the final set of headers looks like:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Basic
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="localhost"
```

I see the only possible workaround for this problem: handle 401 response with some client code that will ask for user credentials (in own dialog) and send request with Basic authentication. I want to avoid this custom code and use the standard browser dialog.

Here is Authentication configuration in IIS

[image]

So my questions are:

1. Is there possibility to suppress other authentication schemes in Unauthorized response of ASP.NET application?
   This will allow to respond only with `WWW-Authenticate: Basic` and will not leave a choice to browser except to use Basic authentication.
2. If no, is there any other way I can have both Windows and Basic authentication for my application, and fallback to Basic authentication if request with Windows authentication fails?

Comment: Your only hope is to set anonymous authentication on IIS, and then take over all the authentication in your ASP.NET app. 401 challenge is not quite difficult to implement if you understand how the headers are composed.

Comment: Thank you for this hint. I was considering this option. It's quite easy to implement Basic authentication filter. But I have no idea how to implement windows authentication. In the request I get the header like `Authorization: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAIIAAAAAUAF4AAAAQABAAcgAAABAAEACyAAAAFYKI4gYBsR0AAAAPU7u7915yFAbuNVMBL3efwkkATQXBCAGwAbwBhAGQAXwB1AHMTDBAZQByADEAQgBZAE0ADMQBEADEAMAAwAJKjvyabinEyAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAXAAPAdU9QBstqYE5Nzg39q1tYclfqwLQRorpUvuUw2ig29PtFE3MorMb4=`. What should I do with it? I haven't found any info how windows authentication could be implemented in custom way.

Comment: A possible way is to use a login page with custom configuration, http://mvolo.com/iis-70-twolevel-authentication-with-forms-authentication-and-windows-authentication/ . Anyway it would be too complicated to go. Get rid of the requirement would be an easier way, as basic authentication is not a good idea in general.